# Filter in django between from date and to date

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-views

More pdf file is saved in table with different dates,How to filter pdf file between fromdate and  todate.

How to filter inbetween dates and list the pdf file.

views.py

```
def select_date(request):
    client = Client.objects.all()
    process = Client_Process.objects.all()
    pdf = Client_files.objects.all()
    today = date.today()
    yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)
    print(today)
    print(yesterday)
    if request.method == "POST":
        fromdate = request.POST.get('fromdate')
        todate = request.POST.get('todate')
        user = Client_files.objects.filter(Date__range=(fromdate,todate))
        print(user)
    return render(request,'select_date.html', {'pdf':pdf,'client':client,'process':process})


models.py

class Client_files(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    client_process = models.ForeignKey(Client_Process, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    File_Name = models.FileField()
    Pages = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Status = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    class Meta:
        db_table : 'client_files'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [**`__date`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date), to convert a datetime to a date first:

```
def select_date(request):
    client = Client.objects.all()
    process = Client_Process.objects.all()
    pdf = Client_files.objects.all()
    today = date.today()
    yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)
    print(today)
    print(yesterday)
    if request.method == "POST":
        fromdate = request.POST.get('fromdate')
        todate = request.POST.get('todate')
        pdf = Client_files.objects.filter(Date__date__range=(fromdate, todate))
        print(pdf)
    return render(request,'select_date.html', {'pdf':pdf,'client':client,'process':process})
```

Usually however when you filter items, you pass the parameters as GET parameters in a GET request. A POST request usually changes data.